# Is Lock protection needed in synchronous functions when using asyncio framework?

Tags: python-asyncio, order-of-execution

My question in a nutshell is, how exactly does the asyncio framework executes code?
Let's say I have some synchronous function which uses some data e.g. in a global variable. This context is fully synchronous, there are no IO-operations. This function will be called by some other functions which are in general asynchronous.
My question now is: Do I need to use a Lock in the synchronous function (then I would have to make it async) to protect the "shared" data of e.g. the global variable?

If I understood it correctly the asyncio framework executes async code until it has to "await" something. But this would mean that this synchronous context will always be executed as a whole and therefore wouldn't need protection by an `asyncio.Lock`, right?

Example:

```py
SHARED_MAP: dict[str, int] = {}

def get_entry(key: str) -> int:
    # Do I need to use a Mutex-Lock here?
    if key not in SHARED_MAP:
        SHARED_MAP[key] = randint(1, 10)

    return SHARED_MAP[key]

async def foo():
    # ...
    entry1 = get_entry("foo")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    entry2 = get_entry("bar")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    # ...

asyncio.run(foo())
```

I fooled around a bit with `asyncio.sleep`s and costly arraycopy operations but the code did not break. So either I'm not good enough to break my code or asyncio indeed exectutes until the next await statement.

PS: If my guess is correct and asyncio executes until the next await statement, can one say in general that if the `Awaitable` is a `Coroutine` that this will be executed immediately? Such that the only blocking things are `Future` objects?

Comment: You are correct. The `asyncio` event loop runs in a single thread, so there is no possibility of race conditions with the shared resource, if only non-`async` functions access it. In typical `async`/`await` code i.e. using `asyncio` (there are special libraries out there that have their own low-level implementations) the only way to allow for a context switch to happen is to `await` something.